# performing partial database update with dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

Given database table Users, (Name, Family Name, Age and Sex). 
I want to create an update statement whereas any of these columns can be null - not edited / coming from client of some kind.
The client creates an object User { Name, FamilyName, Age, Sex }, it will fill only changed properties so basically i'm looking for a way to guess how to build the query and how to send the data to it.

I don't know how to handle this issue at all besides getting whole row and merging it's data with object i've received from client. So far it is what i've done: select > merge > update.

Is there any other way ?

Comment: Could you show more details about your code? What is the class and how do you plan or use it in the update process?

Comment: Given the fact that I continue to receive downvotes on the accepted answer, could you clarify if the most upvoted comment in my answer is correct or not? Even after five years I would like to fix the answer if it is the case.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Suppose that your User class is something like this one

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string FamilyName {get;set;}
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public string Sex { get; set; }

}
```

(Note the int field defined as `Nullable<int>` to allow the insertion of a null value in the corresponding field)

Now, your code that sets the fields, reflecting a null value for your null properties, could be written simply as a normal update. All the stuff required to pass a null value as a parameter is done by the Dapper internals

```
// Initialize just two fields and leave the other to their defaults
// (null for both strings and nullable ints)
User u = new User();
u.UserID = 1;
u.Name = "Steve";
bool ok = UpdateUser(u);
if(ok) ......


public UpdateUser(User info)
{
    using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LOCAL);
                                                Initial Catalog=TestDB;
                                                Integrated Security=True;"))
    {
        cnn.Open();

        // Prepare the parameters to pass to Dapper Execute 
        var pms = new
        {
           UserID = info.UserID   
           FirstName = info.Name,
           FamilyName = info.FamilyName,  // <- this is null
           Age = info.Age,                // <- this is null
           Sex = info.Sex                 // <- this is null
        };

        int rows = cnn.Execute(@"UPDATE [UserTable] 
                                 SET FirstName= @FirstName,
                                     LastName = @LastName, 
                                     Age = @Age, 
                                     Sex = @Sex
                                 WHERE UserID = @UserID",
                                 pms);
         return rows != 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: so you actually saying that Dapper knows to deal with null value for string of an object and will never set database entity with null ? Say we have allow null in some db column wouldn't it be a shame to never update it ?

Comment: If the property is null then Dapper set the corresponding field to null

Comment: Dapper executes your query utilizing the values passed in the parameters collection. If these values are null then Dapper sets the fields to null. If you don't want to touch a field then you should change your query.  In my example all the strings properties but the FirstName are not initialized so they are null. The same for the Nullable<int> and thus also Age is null.

Comment: So in the end this is setting the Age and Sex fields to null. I think that's the opposite of what OP wanted. I believe he wanted to keep those fields with the current value and only update those modified.